# Create AVD (Android Emulator) from the command line, also the Emulator heap size should be 100?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My requirement is install the app into Android emulator in Command line. I can able to install the app, but Emulator should already launched. I want Emulator launch is also in Command line also the heap size of the emulator should be 100 or more than 100. can you guys help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Sri

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a AVD and launch the emulator via the documentation at [Managing AVDs from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).

If you need a special hardware configuration, answer 'yes' at the "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile" prompt and when creating the AVD, and then specify the necessary heap size in the appropriate prompt.